# How to make mounting a certain device read-only?

Tags: usb, permissions, read-only, devices

When I connect my camera to my Xubuntu 18.04 computer, it's mounted with write permissions, which isn't exactly desirable. How can I make it so that it, and any other camera, will be mounted read-only?

This is what mtab shows for it:
`/dev/sdd1 /media/me/king64 exfat rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,uid=1000,gid=1000,fmask=0022,dmask=0022,iocharset=utf8,namecase=0,errors=remount-ro 0 0`

But sdd1 could be anything else too, so adding that line to fstab with ro wouldn't be a proper solution. Better than nothing sure, but is there another way?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to mount a USB device in read only mode?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/250551/how-to-mount-a-usb-device-in-read-only-mode)

Comment: FYI: Are you aware that *flavors* of Ubuntu only come with three years of supported life (five years applies to Ubuntu Desktop, Ubuntu Server but not flavors), so you're asking about a release that is EOL.  (https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2020/08/14/ubuntu-18-04-5-lts-released/ or a recent UWN - https://wiki.ubuntu.com/UbuntuWeeklyNewsletter/Issue681#Lubuntu_18.04_LTS_End_of_Life_and_Current_Support_Statuses highlights the EOL notices for Lubuntu/Ubuntu-MATE/Kubuntu/Ubuntu-Budgie; Xubuntu didn't announce EOL but refer https://xubuntu.org/release/18-04/ you'll see it's 29 April 2021)

Comment: @24601 Not really, It's helpful-ish, but doesn't really answer much. I looked into things, and it seems like Thunar has a volume manager that automatically mounts removable media and stuff. How to get that thingie to detect cameras and mount them as read-only would be *the* answer.

One potential solution would be to mount stuff under the Removable Storage section and check the photo importing option under Camera section, which takes a custom command, which could be a remount command. Dunno if it'd work, and it'd be a hack at best. Maybe it's just best to mount manually.

Comment: @guiverc Ah, oh. Thanks for the info, I'll go get the latest LTS. I'm fairly sure it doesn't matter in this particular instance, but yeah.